# How to prove that (R*, x) is associative?

Tags: group-theory, associativity

I understand that (R*, x) (under multiplication) is a group, where R* is the real numbers excluding 0.

It has an identity element (1)

Has an inverse (1/x for all x in the group)

but I am unsure how to prove its associativity.

Comment: What is $R?$ The real numbers? Proving associativity for the real numbers depends on how you define the real numbers.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How you prove it has an inverse? Did you proof inverse exist for Q*. Then argue inverse exist for R*? For associative, you can also proof it for Z*, then argue associative for Q*, and then argue associative for R*.  Here is some [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134588/how-does-one-prove-that-addition-on-mathbbr-is-associative)

Comment: If this is for a first course in group theory, your teacher probably just expects you to say that associativity is well known: $x(yz)=(xy)z$ for all reals $x,y,z$.